# How to compare data from two different array in Laravel 5.4 using Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

My main concern is to check the available quantity of a particular product from database and compare that with the **Cart** item which saved in session I guess. I am getting the "$id" from a DB product and adding it to Cart. But I also need to check the available quantity to control the increase of "qty" from Cart.

So far I managed to do this but failed to get the result yet.

```
    // Test Cart Functions
public function addCart($id)
{
    $products = MarketProduct::find($id);

    $cartItem = Cart::content();

    $check = array();
    foreach ($cartItem as $one) {
        $check[$one['id']] = true;
    }
    foreach ($products as $two) {
        if (isset($check[$two])) {
           return 'Match!';
        }
    }

    // foreach(Cart::search(id) as $cartproduct)
    //       {
    //          return $cartproduct->options->available_quantity; 
    //       }

    $available_quantity = $products->product->available_quantity;

    // $cart->search(function ($cartItem, $rowId) {
    // return $cartItem->id === $id;
    // });

    $result = Cart::add([
        'id' => $id,
        'name' => $products->title,
        'qty' => 1,
        'price' => $products->mrp(),
        'options' => [
            'image' => $products->thumbnail(),
            'available_quantity' => $available_quantity
            ]
        ]);

    //$totalcart = Cart::content();

    // foreach($totalcart as $cartitem){

    //     if($cartitem->id == $products->product->id){

    //     }
    // }

    return redirect()->back();



}
```

I have to match the requested $id with the Cart items 'id' not with the rowId from Cart package.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Cart::search() to compare against the provided id and get the collection of $cartItem which matches.

If you for instance want to find all items with an id of 1:

```
$cart->search(function ($cartItem, $rowId) {
    return $cartItem->id === 1; 
});
```

Check documentation for more detail: https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart

Comment: I need to get the Cart items 'id' from requested $id which will match with each other, not with the rowId from Cart package